# Proper course for one realizing he is eating something forbidden

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food

Suppose one was eating a piece of chicken, and he finds out it was from a non slaughtered chicken. Does Halacha require him to try to throw up?

Comment: That wouldn't change the fact that he ate it.

Comment: @Daniel: 100%. However should he just leave it or not? By throwing up he is absorbing less of it.